# Breeze: Query data from unmapped table in Entity Framwork + SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, breeze

I have:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<SystemTypes> GetSystemTypes()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Set<SystemTypes>();
    }
```

This method will return an array of `SystemTypes` object. `SystemTypes` is a class which is defined before.

Question 1: how can I write a dynamically method that only need type name and return an array of objects belong to that type?

Example:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<dynamictype> GetDynamicTypes(string TypeName)
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.Set<TypeName>();
    }
```

Question 2: in my database, I have table A which is create by a SQL script. `DbContext` doesn't know about A. Do BreezeJs or Entity FrameWork support to query from table A (we only know table name)? If do, please tell me how.

Comment: If table `A` is not known to your `DbContext`, you cannot query it using EF.

Comment: @marc_s : Do we have any solutions to let DbContext know A ? If I have a dll file which define A, Do it give any help?

Comment: If you want to query table `A` with Entity Framework, you **must** add it to the `DbContext` - that's the only solution

Comment: The solution is: must add to DbContext. But How can i do it dynamically without drop Model or use Migrations (since i dont want use command)? Do you have any ideas? Please help.